# Error while trying to delete all sheets except specific ones

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete all the sheets in the workbook except month end sheets for a given year eg of sheet names all sheet names are entered in this format dd.mm.yy
I tried other codes like case instead of If but all codes seems to stop at ws.delete

```
Sub Delete_Sheets
    Yr = InputBox("Use YY format only.", "Which year to keep?", 18)

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "31.01.Yr" Or ws.Name <> "28.02.Yr" Or ws.Name <> "31.03.Yr" Or ws.Name <> "30.04.Yr" Or ws.Name <> "31.05.Yr" Or ws.Name <> "30.06.Yr" Or ws.Name <> "31.07.Yr" Or ws.Name <> "31.08.Yr" Or ws.Name <> "30.09.Yr" Or ws.Name <> "31.10.Yr" Or ws.Name <> "30.11.Yr" Or ws.Name <> "31.12.Yr" Then        
            ws.Delete
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True    
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is gonna stop when is trying to delete the last sheet on your workbook. Your current code deletes every sheet. You must use `And` instead of `Or`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use [Application.InputBox method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) instead of `InputBox` only. This one has a `Type:=1` parameter that forces the user to enter numbers only.
- Make sure you test for `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count > 1` because you cannot delete the last worksheet. At least 1 worksheet must remain.
- Put all the sheets you want to skip into an array `SkipSheets` and filter that array for your worksheet name `(UBound(Filter(SkipSheets, ws.Name)) > -1)`

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteSheets()
    Dim InputYear As Variant
    InputYear = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Use YY format only.", Title:="Which year to keep?", Default:=18, Type:=1)

    If VarType(InputYear) = vbBoolean And InputYear = False Then Exit Sub 'user pressed cancel

    Dim SkipSheets() As Variant
    SkipSheets = Array("31.01." & InputYear, "28.02." & InputYear, "31.03." & InputYear, "30.04." & InputYear, "31.05." & InputYear, "30.06." & InputYear, "31.07." & InputYear, "31.08." & InputYear, "30.09." & InputYear, "31.10." & InputYear, "30.11." & InputYear, "31.12." & InputYear)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not (UBound(Filter(SkipSheets, ws.Name)) > -1) And ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
            ws.Delete
        End If
    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it it doesn't give an error but it doesn't delete them.

Comment: @Younis That cannot be I tested the code definitly deletes all workbooks that are NOT named like the last day of a month in the year you entered in the box. Note it does not work if you have only 1 worksheet left (the last worksheet cannot be deleted in Excel).

Comment: Does it has anything to do with the format dd.mn.yy being text not a number

Comment: Can you show an example set of names that don't get deletet?

Comment: If i choose yr = 18 e.g sheets to keep 31.01.18 or 28.02.18 or 29.02.18 or 30.09.18 e.g sheets to delete 10.01.18 or 31.01.19 or 02.02.18 etc

Comment: @Younis Just tested. I named my worksheets like that and everything was deleted/keept correctly. Are you sure you are running exactly my code? Do you use a button to run the code? If yes make sure it is linked to the correct macro. Please run it step by step using F8 to see what happens.

Comment: I don't use a button i tried f8 ws.name ="sheet1" and the yellow bar doesn't stop at ws.delete

Comment: Note it does not work with only 1 sheet. You need 2 sheets at least. Excel cannot delete the last sheet (because epmty workbooks are not allowed).

Comment: Please remove the `Application.DisplayAlerts` lines and try again.

Comment: I am using the exact code I tried also removing display alerts lines didn't work ... does it have something to do with excel 2010?

Comment: That is very strang, actually this code is so simple I don't see how it could fail at all (and actually it works for me perfectly). If you put a message box where `ws.Delete` is does it appear? Eg `MsgBox "I would delete " & ws.Name & " now."`

Comment: Ws.name object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: @did you put the message box *after* the `ws.delete`? If yes, then this means that delete worked!

Comment: Yes but all sheets are there

Comment: Test it on a new workbook. Add some sheets (some which would stay, some which would be deleted) and add the code. It definitely works.

Comment: I did a test but nothing happens ...are u sure it is not a 2010 issue ?

Comment: @Younis Well, I cannot verify it (I don't have Excel 2010) but I'm pretty sure it should work in 2010 too. Otherwise the code would throw an error (If I used a function that did not exist in 2010 yet). • Actually I have no idea why it doesn't work for you. • What happens if you replace `ws.Delete` with `MsgBox "I would delete " & ws.Name & " now."` so that we get a box instead of deleting the sheet (test this in a workbook with less than 10 sheets or it will show you many boxes).

Comment: Still it is not showing a msgbox when i run it no errors but it will not perform anything

Comment: Maybe a `ThisWorkbook` vs. `ActiveWorkbook` problem?

Comment: It worked only when i used it as this workbook macro but not a personal workbook macro can you please tell me why ?

Comment: Thank you! and sorry if I wasted your time.

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach. Since you don't want to delete the last day of every month and looks like all the sheets are the same:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Delete_Sheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, Month As Date, DontDelete As String, Yr As Integer

StartAgain:
    On Error Resume Next
    Yr = InputBox("Use YY format only.", "Which year to keep?", 18)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Yr = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You didn't enter a valid value. Please Try Again"
        GoTo StartAgain
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not ws.Name Like "??.??.??" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count > 1 Then
            ws.Delete
            GoTo NextSheet
        End If
        Month = DateSerial(Yr, Mid(ws.Name, 4, 2), 1)
        DontDelete = Format(Application.EoMonth(Month, 0), "dd.mm.yy")
        If Not ws.Name = DontDelete Then
            ws.Delete
        End If
NextSheet:
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Edit: I've edited some code but it can't throw any error. Now it shouldn't delete some worksheet that it did. But there is no way you get an error.

Here is the result of the code:

[image: Before:]

[image: After:]

Comment: You need also to test for `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count > 1` before you `.Delete` otherwise it could possibly try to delete the last remaining sheet which then fails. • And `Month = Mid(ws.Name, 4, 2)` errors if it returns a string.

Comment: Yeah @Pᴇʜ that's a possibility. But I'm assuming his workbook has hundreds of sheets and will have the last day of every month, so it shouldn't delete all the sheets. But indeed is a possibility. I've aimed for the simplicity of the code getting dynamically the last day of the month on every iteration so there is no need to fill the array or anything.

Comment: I just mentioned it because actually the OP run into exactly this error because the OPs code tries to delete *all* the sheets because his `If` is always true. E.g. If he enters a year that doesn't exist he will end up in the editor with an uncaught error.

Comment: Yes, I've told him that on the OP, but I've tested this code and works fine.

Comment: unless someone adds a sheet that contains a string, and unless nobody enters a year that does not exist in the workbook. In both casese you end up with uncaught errors.

Comment: @Younis would you mind debugging where in the code is giving you the error?

Comment: Month = Mid(ws.Name, 4, 2)

Comment: And what is the value for `ws.Name` ?

Comment: Value is "Sheet1"

Comment: @Damian I told you in my fist comment that this will fail ^^

Comment: @Younis I've edited my answer, that should fix everything now. And yes Pᴇʜ, that gave errors... I should of known not everyone handles these things.

Comment: @Damian Just a good rule I always try to follow: If a value is originating *possibly* from a user input (sheet names could be user input) then never assume anything (about format or whatever) and validate instead. This makes your code a lot more safe against any code breaks. Even I you as a programmer cannot imagine how something could go wrong, I bet your users will definitly find a way to proof you wrong (happened so many times to me). They always find a way to input something stupid ;)

Comment: The eternal race between programmer and user... Thought I'm not a programmer. Just a VBA enthusiastic :D

Comment: @Younis I had an error which would delete some worksheets.. Fixed it and there is no way that the code before or this would throw you any error now.

Comment: In the screenshot I can find that 28.02.18 got deleted

Comment: Yes, my code had an error, but it was sorted. So it won't delete it now. Anyway, nor the previous code nor the corrected should throw you any error, because they are all handled.

Comment: Sry why saving to personal macro wont let this work ? I am a noob ^^

Comment: Because the code is working on the workbook which has the code, not the one with the worksheets. That's the problem all along, both for @Pᴇʜ and for me. You need to  `Set wb = Workbooks("NameOfTheWorkbooksWithTheSheets.xlsx")` (don't forget the file extension) and then `For Each ws in wb.Worksheets` instead `Thisworkbook`

Comment: Oh sorry to waste both of your time and thank you both for the help ..What if I don't want to mention the file name i want yo use it on active workbooks ill be using this for many workbooks