# VBA: inputbox and cancel button

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

```
varInput = Application.InputBox("Text", "Title", Type:=2)
If varInput = "False" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

If the cancel button is pressed, the return value is a string with "False".
**But on some computer with german setting I will get "Falsch" !**

How should be this handled?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55449103/7558682) you can read how to from @Pᴇʜ. The question has nothing in common with yours, but part of the code handles this. See if it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You must always also test the type of the variable  to be boolean: `VarType(varInput) = vbBoolean` when using the `Application.InputBox`.

```
Dim varInput As Variant
varInput = Application.InputBox("Text", "Title", Type:=2)

If VarType(varInput) = vbBoolean And varInput = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

If you test only for `False` …

```
If varInput = False Then
```

… then it will also exit sub if you enter `0` or `Falsch` (in german Excel) or `False` (in English Excel).

This hapens because a string of `0` or `"Falsch"` (or `"False"`) automatically casts into a boolean if compared with `False`. But only the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button returns a true boolean.

Comment: Very nice approach.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes:

```
If varInput = False Then
```

Comment: In that case it works if I press cancel, but it fails if I write something and press OK. The varIpunt is than string containg e.g. "test" and it fails on the modified line.

Comment: @Meloun  Explicitly declare `varInput` as *Variant* rather than *String*.

Comment: @patrick you must also test for `VarType(varInput) = vbBoolean` otherwise it will exit sub also on values like `0` or `Falsch` (in OP's case). See my answer.